# Сохранение panel в виде картинки

Tags: c#, winforms

Сделал простецкую рисовалку на компоненте panel. При сохранении в виде картинки сохраняется пустая панель без нарисованных элементов.

Вот что нарисовано в программе
[image]

Вот как сохраняет
[image]

```
private void panel2_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    if (IsClicked)
    {
        PrevPoint = CurrentPoint;
        CurrentPoint = e.Location;
        for_paint();
    }
}

private void panel2_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    IsClicked = true;
    CurrentPoint = e.Location;
}


private void for_paint()
{
    Pen p = new Pen(CurrentColor);
    g.DrawLine(p, PrevPoint, CurrentPoint);
}

private void panel2_MouseUp(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    IsClicked = false;
}
```

Реализация рисования на панели

```
 using (Bitmap graphicSurface = new Bitmap(panel2.Width, panel2.Height))
 {
     using (StreamWriter bitmapWriter = new StreamWriter("TEST.JPEG"))
     {
         panel2.DrawToBitmap(graphicSurface, new Rectangle(0, 0, panel2.Width, panel2.Height));
         graphicSurface.Save(bitmapWriter.BaseStream, ImageFormat.Jpeg);
     }
```

Сохранение в виде картинки. Пробовал 3 разных кода и везде сохраняет пустой panel.

Comment: `Pen` тоже надо оборачивать в `using`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Сверни и разверни окно - получится тот же результат.

Надо изначально рисовать на `Bitmap`е, который внутри обработчика `Paint` перерисовывать на панели. Кстати, в таком случае и проблемы с сохранением нет.

Comment: Можете помочь ?  Я рисование только сегодня начал чуть-чуть осваивать.

Comment: @Андрей, что именно непонятно в моём описании?

Comment: "Надо изначально рисовать на Bitmapе, который внутри обработчика Paint перерисовывать на панели". Не понял как именно рисовать на bitmap.

Comment: @Андрей, new Bitmap, Graphics.FromBitmap, а остальное уже есть,

Comment: Graphics.FromBitmap - этот так и надо писать ?

Comment: @Андрей, https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.drawing.graphics.fromimage(v=vs.110).aspx - первая же гуглоссылка, несмотря на то, что он действительно не `FromBitmap`, a `FromImage`...

Comment: Потому я и спросил, потому что не нашел этого метода. Спасибо большое.

Comment: @Андрей, Image - это базовый класс Bitmap'а.